# SvelteKit, import type LayoutServerLoad/PageLoad

Tags: sveltekit

In `layout.server.ts` I try to

```js
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';
```

but the type can't be found:

> '"./$types"' has no exported member named 'LayoutServerLoad'. Did you mean 'LayoutServerData'?

What do I need to do to get the type `LayoutServerLoad` (or `PageLoad` or `PageServerLoad` ...) in `./$types`?

Comment: You don't need to import these types any more if you're using VS Code with the latest version of the Svelte for VS Code extension installed (or one of other specific set-ups mentioned on the page linked to), and in fact removing them is what fixed this problem for me. https://svelte.dev/blog/zero-config-type-safety#type-safety-without-types

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- The file has to be called `+layout.server.ts` (or for another load action, one of the other fixed names, [see docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load))
- The Vite dev server has to be running, which watches the files and generates the types when a file is changed
- (The `tsconfig.json` has to extend `.svelte-kit\tsconfig.json`, which defines `rootDirs`, so the generated types are resolved. This should already be the case, judging by the suggestion for `LayoutServerData`.)

Comment: _The Vite dev server has to be running_ is the part I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great reminder to *actually start your dev server first*.

Answer (score 3):

For me, just an "npm update" worked.

Comment: Looks like more suitable for a comment

Comment: Indeed sorry for the mistake