# How to Import Types in SvelteKit - PageLoad / PageServerLoad

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I'm trying to import the `PageLoad` function for the SvelteKit load function according to the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load).

The import does not seem to exist. This is a brand new app with the latest version of SvelteKit. It will find the `PageLoadData` just fine.

**src/routes/+page.server.ts**

[image: +page.server.ts]

I also tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060175/sveltekit-import-type-layoutserverload-pageload), but I am already doing everything it says.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Have you tried restarting the dev server? You can also remove the types file (`.svelte-kit/types/src/routes/$types.d.ts`) and see what gets generated/regenerated.

Comment: By the way, the type is in the wrong place, it should be `load: PageServerLoad`.

Comment: I restarted VS Code and it worked.  I swear I did that several times before.  Weird.  Thanks!

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of [SvelteKit, import type LayoutServerLoad/PageLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060175/sveltekit-import-type-layoutserverload-pageload)

Comment: For anyone reading this, the automatic type creation is buggy.  You have to restart vs-code sometimes when you rename or create a new route, and you have to `npm run dev` on and off again for it to work.

Comment: Can try `@command:svelte.restartLanguageServer`: 
Press `shift+cmd+p` (or `shift+ctrl+p` for windows and linux), search and select `Svelte: Restart Language Server`.

Comment: I'm using import like this `import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types.js';`and everything works as intended.