# SvelteKit PageLoad module not found

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project and for some reason, `./$types` doesn't have the module PageLoad (which other projects do. I'm not sure what I did/didn't do to not have it. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Module '"./$types"' has no exported member 'PageLoad'.ts(2305)
```

This is how I'm using it (for testing):

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageLoad = async ({ params, fetch }) => {
  console.log('props from +page.ts: ', params.db_item)
  // We fetch the post here using a Worker/Lambda
  return params.db_item
}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "playwright test",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check .",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "surge deploy": "rollup -c; surge public"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.25.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "next",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.7.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.7.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.6",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4",
        "vite": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "svelte-share-buttons-component": "^1.5.0"
    }
}
```

Here is my svelte.config file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SvelteKit, import type LayoutServerLoad/PageLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74060175/sveltekit-import-type-layoutserverload-pageload)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is absolutely crazy, but I figured it out.

I had initially named the file `+page.js` and *renamed* it to `.ts`. Apparently, that throws everything off. After deleting the file and *creating* it with .ts extension, the `$types` import worked perfectly. Nowhere does it say anything in the documentation, but that's what it was.

Comment: You should tell the sveltekit team about this. Thanks for the finding.

Comment: I did. That's where I found the fix. :)

Comment: For future googlers, I just found out that I was trying to call `PageLoad` inside a `+layout.ts` file, which is a wrong thing to do. We can only call `PageLoad` if we have a `+page.ts` and `ServerLoad` for `+layout.ts`.

Comment: @JoelHager - would you mind linking to the GitHub issue or wherever else you found the fix? I have been looking for it but unable to find it

Comment: There wasn't a specific 'fix' for it. It's some common knowledge thing about how Svelte builds types. You either have to force a type rebuild (I think npm run check would do it) but I ended up deleting the file after copying, and just creating a new file with the .ts extension. I wish I could be of more help. :/

Answer (score 3):

Per the Svelte Blog: [Zero-effort type safety](https://svelte.dev/blog/zero-config-type-safety)

SvelteKit creates a hidden file `$types.d.ts` in every route directory. This file contains route specific types. Because of this, it's no longer even necessary to annotate Svelte-specific file exports (`+page`, `+layout`, `+server`, `hooks`, `params`, etc.).

However, when the name of a `.ts/.js` file in a particular route changes, the route's `$types.d.ts` file may loose integrity.

You can fix the problem by restarting the Svelte language server.

In VSCode:

- `ctrl+p`
- Enter `>`
- Select "Svelte: Restart Language Server"

Comment: I tried restarting the language server, and it did not work for me. I had to delete the file and create it under .ts extension rather than rename it from .js to .ts. Maybe it was a one-off bug, but recreating the file is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

One other time you'll run into this is if you've added a new file but aren't running the development server. In this case, the `$types.d.ts` file won't have been generated yet.

In that case, the fix is just to run your local dev server.

Comment: `Yup, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this trouble - I found issues caused by moving from Svelte 3.X to Svelte 4.X, where my `.eslintrc.cjs` was still referencing some old "`svelte3`" configuration.

### My outdated config:

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier'],
    plugins: ['svelte3', '@typescript-eslint'],
    ignorePatterns: ['*.cjs'],
    overrides: [{ files: ['*.svelte'], processor: 'svelte3/svelte3' }],
    settings: {
        'svelte3/typescript': () => require('typescript'),
    },
    // ...
}
```

### Steps to fix.

1. Replace `.eslintrc.js` by copying latest config from a SvelteKit project generated with `npm create svelte@latest my-app` (also shared below)
2. Stop running dev server
3. Remove any generated types by deleting the `.svelte-kit` directory
4. Generate new types with `npx svelte-kit sync`
5. Reload VS Code window, some files may still be showing old errors but as soon as you edit them, they will display correctly

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:svelte/recommended',
        'prettier',
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    parserOptions: {
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte'],
    },
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2017: true,
        node: true,
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.svelte'],
            parser: 'svelte-eslint-parser',
            parserOptions: {
                parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
            },
        },
    ],
};
```