# How to use TS in svelte +page files?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm confused by the svelte-kit docs.

I started an empty project, trying to get to know svelte, trying to create a basic app.

I want to do dynamic routes and as a base for my +page.ts file i used [this](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js).

I see types being imported via the jsdoc annotation, but how do I import them the usual way, like `import { Stuff } from "./$types"`. This doesn't seem to work. And actually the `PageLoad` type imported via jsdoc syntax also doesn't provide any typing - I see a warning saying that `params` has `any` type.

Is there a good basic example app written in TypeScript? Examples that I found were outdated.

I'm using WebStorm.

[image]

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74060175/546730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular import syntax should work, but the dev server has to be running for the types to be generated in the first place. (Alternatively you can run `svelte-kit sync` to update the types once.)

Comment: Ok, I can import the type, but it still doesn't seem to work. The code works, but the types in WebStorm don't. I updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: You are using the type the wrong way. `PageLoad` is not for the argument, it's the whole function: `export const load: PageLoad = ({ params }) => ...`